# Using ESP8266-01 via Arduino(no flash) without AT commands(using serial monitor)

Tags: esp8266, flash, arduino-uno-wifi-dev-ed

I'm trying to build a smart Keychain using Arduino uno wifi(org, so Im using it like it's Arduino uno), ESP8266-01 And neo6m GPS device.

My esp8266 wasn't new, and it came without AT firmware. I flashed it so it could have AT commands but it's not completely working.

Anyway, the flash is using 115200 baud and I'd like to use serial monitor to communicate it using arduino(and blynk app).
Is there a way could I do it without flashing the esp for 9600 baud rate?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean? How can I use it? My Arduino uno wifi board is Arduino.org which means(I read online) that until Arduino won't provide proper TCP library I can't really communicate with it online

Comment: your information is obsolete. you can use it as any Uno with external esp8266 on SoftwareSerial. read the answer

Answer (score 1):

Arduino Uno WiFi Dev Ed has the on-board esp8266 wired to additional Serial interface (I2C to Serial adapter). With [UnoWiFiDevEdSerial1](https://github.com/jandrassy/UnoWiFiDevEdSerial1) library you can use the on-board esp8266 and have Serial free for Serial Monitor and sketch upload. The EspProxy tool enables upload to the on-board esp8266 over the ATmega (passing bytes between Serial and Serial1).
I am the author of the UnoWiFiDevEdSerial1 library.

Comment: The thing is, I'm not able to use this library in order to do exactly that. Maybe im not trying right, but I did try it, and my professor said I must use esp8266-01 module. I can't use it with software serial without reflashing because software serial is up to 9600 baud rate and my esp is using 115200 baud rate.

Comment: what did you try? AT firmware or WiFiLink or your own esp8266 sketch

Comment: Doing this exactly https://github.com/jandrassy/UnoWiFiDevEdSerial1

Comment: but that library is like SoftwareSerial. it is only the gate to esp8266

Comment: did you try WiFiLink firmware? with WiFiLink library it can Arduino networking like WiFi or Ethernet library

Comment: @MaorGorelik, did you solve it?